# Laravel 5.5 connect your class in the controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is a file "MyClasses.php" in the folder "App":

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Model1 extends Model {}
class Model2 extends Model {}
```

How to connect it in the controller using use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read about PSR-4 standards:
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

MyClasses.php is not a valid name for a model in this case, because a) none of the classes defined inside of it are called `MyClasses` and b) there are numerous class definitions in this file.

```
// App/Model1.php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Model1 extends Model {
    protected $table = 'some_table';
}

// Controller
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model1;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $record = Model1::where('some_field', 1)->get();
    }
}
```

EDIT: to clarify.
Both models should be in their own files, called Model1.php and Model2.php under the App folder. Also, you model names * should * correspond to the table names they are accessing. So if for example Model1 is going to be bound to table `user_confirmations` you should rename your file and class to `UserConfirmations` - this would be considered best practice.